# ensure safe url nodejs

Tags: node.js, security, url, path, relative-path

I'm using nodejs, and part of my site will be just simply serving files, basically using `fs.readFile` on a certain directory containing public files. For example, when you request `mydomain.com:1234/hello/info.html` my script will request the file `publicfiles/hello/info.html` and send the results to the client. However, I am aware that if an attacker entered in `mydomain.com:1234/../evilurl/userpasswords.txt` nodejs will try to get file `publicfiles/../evilurl/userpasswords.txt`, which is really the same as `evilurl/userpasswords.txt`, so in other words, they could access files out of the `publicfiles` directory and access "secure" information. I know I could protect against this by simply making sure that `req.url` doesn't contain `..`, but are there any other way a user could access bad files? Could they use some kind of escape sequence instead of `..` that means the same thing? Also, I do not want to use express for this. If there is a library specifically for this, I am fine, but I don't want a huge framework like express.

Comment: Express is not a "huge framework".  You should use it.  Or just use https://npmjs.org/package/st

Comment: @SLaks i guess you're right. I mean, express is just a routing framework. Oh yeah, it also has request managements. That is all. No wait, it also can handle views. Only three major features. That is all. No, wait, it also happens to have session management as well. You get the idea.

Comment: @Markasoftware Not sure what you mean by "*request management*." Middleware? If so, the bulk of that is entirely opt-in. You have to `use()` them explicitly -- including `session()` management. And, Express does not support views; it offers a light, general wrapper over view engines. And, if you don't want to use a view engine, then don't. You can `write()`/`end()`, `send()`, or `sendfile()`.

Comment: @SLaks Why not just use the relevant function -  https://github.com/isaacs/st/blob/master/st.js#L195

Comment: @levi: Because properly serving static files requires more than just dots.

Comment: I'm not saying you HAVE to use views, but express still has them in it. Technically, just because you have a computer you don't HAVE to use it. if you can program HTML5 WebGL doesn't mean you HAVE to use it for 3d graphics. If you have a gaming computer it doesn't mean you HAVE to turn up the graphics settings in your video games. And yes, just because you use express doesn't mean you HAVE to use sessions, views, or middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too advocate using a ready-made package for serving static content. I would go so far as to say you should use httpd/ngnix to serve your static content.

That being said, you could use `path.resolve()`. Resolve the request path against your base `publicfiles/` directory, and make sure that the result has your `publicfiles/` as prefix. If it doesn't, then that's a bad request.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of path.resolve, I have been able to make it work. It would have been better if you could provide some example code and a link to documentation, but this is fine. Thanks! Also, I don't want to use Apache/httpd because I also have some parts of the same project that use node for more than static file serving.